# blueimp - jquery fileupload onClick event

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

We are using Blueimp Jquery File Upload.

How do we add a button to fire the upload?

Right now the upload occurs as soon as a user selects a file.
We would like to have the user select files then click a UPLOAD NOW button.

I have changed the JS file, turned on the autoUplaod to false, but can figure out how to get the OnClick to work.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for add function callback:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        },
        add:function (e, data) {
           $("#uploadBtn").off('click').on('click',function () {           
             data.submit();
           });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @roasted that .off('click').on('click', function () {... trick is absolutely awesome. Thank you so much! If I could I would honestly kiss you man

Comment: How do you call data.send() from outside the plugin code? What if I want to start the uploads from another ajax request, that's unrelated?  `$('#some-unrelated-form').on('ajax:complete', function () { //start upload here });`

Comment: @Mohammad you might be interested in reading the following page https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Submit-files-asynchronously

Answer (score -1):

i tried modifying the "add" function, and it kinda works except that in all of internet explorer browsers the file selected does not appear in the input box.  also, in my experience, if you changed it multiple times before the button click, all the files get uploaded.  this worked for me:
1.  do not instantiate the blueimp fileupload object right away
2.  create a function that basically instantiates the fileupload object
3.  attach the function in #2 above to a button click
i realize there are some redundancies in my code below.  also i force the IframeTransport, you can probably do a browser check for that one.  you can also do the browser check for the add function, for ie you can use "fileInput", for everyone else you can use "file".  this works fine for me in all browsers, except for the progress bar, i need to tween the "forceIframeTransport" to check the browser

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        /*do your jquery stuff here, but do not call fileupload*/
        $("btnUpload").click(function(){
            /*i can add additional post params*/
            /*some of this is redundant*/
            var post = Array({name:"hello", value:"there"});
            uploadFileOnClick("fileupload", $("#fileupload") ,post, true);
        });
    });
    function uploadFileOnClick(id, file, post, _autoUpload) {
        $('#'+id).fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            multipart: true,
            autoUpload: true,
            formData: post,
            forceIframeTransport: true,
            progress: function (e, data) {
                /*insert progress code here*/
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                /*insert your code here*/
            }
        });
        if (_autoUpload) {
            $('#'+id).fileupload('add', {files: file});
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="somename" data-url="yourserver.php?goeshere=true"/>
    </form>
    <!-- i use a link in my case, it will work if you use a button in the form as well-->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnUpload">Upload</a>
</body>
```